# Boot Camp: How should I partition for Windows XP, FAT or NTFS?

Tags: windows-xp, mac, macbook, partitioning, boot-camp

I've read quite an [old article on Ask Dave Taylor (Boot Camp was still beta)](http://www.askdavetaylor.com/how_do_i_install_windows_xp_on_my_mac_using_boot_camp_1.html) and he says to format the Windows XP partition with FAT; Mac OS X can't browse NTFS partitions.

I have a new MacBook Pro (bought Oct 2010) with Snow Leopard. Can I go for NTFS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard process is to start with a single Mac partition (HFS+ format), then run Boot Camp Assistant.  It'll split the drive, and create a FAT32 partition for Windows (which will be converted to NTFS later), and also play some tricks with the disk's partition map to turn it into a hybrid GPT+MBR format (note: this is the reason you should use BCA rather than partitioning it yourself).  Then, you boot from the Windows installer disk, have it reformat the FAT partition to NTFS (note: be very careful how you do this, so it doesn't damage the partition map and/or Mac volume -- BCA has instructions, read them) and install Windows.  Finally, put in your OS X install disk, and Windows will see it as a driver install disk (incl. a driver to get access to the Mac partition).

Note that Mac OS X can read NTFS, but cannot (by default) write to it; you can change this (see Ryan's answer for instructions), but I've heard of cases where it's corrupted the NTFS volume.  Apple leaves this disabled for a reason...

Answer (score 2):

Actually, Mac OS X has had the ability to browse NTFS as read-only since 10.3. With Snow Leopard, you can not only read NTFS partitions, but you can actually write to them to.

Here is a tutorial on how to enable the ability to write to the NTFS partion: http://smokingapples.com/software/tutorials/snow-leopards-hidden-ntfs-readwrite-support/