# How do I write to an NTFS-formatted USB portable HDD using a Mac?

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, ntfs

I have a Western Digital USB portable HDD and a MacBook Pro running 10.6.4. Is the link referred in this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/199784/boot-camp-how-should-i-partition-for-windows-xp-fat-or-ntfs/199792#199792) still applicable? The link points to a October 2009 blog entry, which I think is rather outdated considering I have Mac OS 10.6.4.

How do I write to an NTFS-formatted USB portable HDD using a Mac?

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, there are mixed results. It also seems that nobody who writes about it actually tested it. If your data is *that* worthless, go ahead :-)

[This](https://superuser.com/questions/176978/mac-os-x-10-6-4-and-ntfs-writing) might also interest you. I'd estimate many more people go the NTFS-3g way than what's in the blog post.

Besides, what is the goal of your question? NTFS-3g is even mentioned in that blog post, and in the SU thread you link to. "How do I write to an NTFS-formatted USB portable HDD using a Mac" is clearly answered.

Comment: Yes, NTFS-3g was mentioned, but I didn't find any indication of the blog post being still applicable (it was dated Oct 2009, eons ago in the Internet time scale). Add to the fact that there were apprehensions about the method. And according to your answer, there _still_ are apprehensions about enabling NTFS writing in OS X. I'd better make backups then `:)`

Comment: @Kit Snow Leopard was released in September 2009. While it looks like an unsupported feature that could conceivably break in minor releases, I guess this info is as current as it's going to get for something like this (without trying it yourself).